# Proof of $r_{cr,cl} = k/h$ (Critical radius of insulation of cylindrical shapes)

Tags: thermodynamics

Can you please help me to show the derivation of **critical radius of insulation** equation $$r_{cr,cyl} = k/h$$
I start from heat transfer in cylindrical shape equation: 
$$\dot Q = \frac{T_1 - T_\infty}{\frac{ln(r_2/r_1)}{2\pi Lk}+\frac{1}{h(2\pi r_2L)}}$$
Next, by plotting $\dot Q$
 vs $r_2$, I conclude that $d\dot Q/dr_2=0$ is the max heat transfer.

 [image]
Therefore:
$$\frac{T_1 - T_\infty}{\frac{ln(r_2/r_1)}{2\pi Lk}+\frac{1}{h(2\pi r_2L)}} =0$$
$$\frac{T_1 2\pi Lk}{ln(r_2/r_1)}=T_\infty h 2\pi r_2 L$$
Here I draw an assumption that at max $\dot Q$ the $T_1 = T_\infty$ (Is this valid assumption?). So everything simplifies to:
$$\frac{k}{ln(r_2/r_1)}=hr_2$$

And this is where I am stuck. By what assumption or relation can I eliminate $ln(r_2/r_1)$ ??

Comment: Please provide more details on how you got that derivative.

Comment: @ChesterMiller, heat transfer rate, or $\dot Q /dr$ ? If later, I thought it was clear. I multiplied both sides by $dr_2$ then equated $d\dot Q$ to zero, right?
If former, hmm, that's just an equation for heat transfer of insulated wire. $\dot Q = \frac{T_1 - T_2}{R_{tot}}$.

Comment: You need to go back and review differentiation, particularly the quotient rule.  You are trying to determine $d\dot{Q}/dr_2$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! Thank you! Let me look into that.

Comment: That $r_2$ being in ln() and out, and about throws me completely off. Any help ?

Comment: Let's see your differentiation of $\dot{Q}$ with respect to $r_2$

Comment: $$\frac{d\dot{Q}}{dr_2}=0=\frac{\Big((T_1-T_\infty)2\pi L k h \Big)\cdot \Big(hr_2 ln(r_2/r_1)+k\Big)-\Big((T_1-T_\infty)2\pi  L  k h r_2\Big)\cdot\Big(h\cdot ln(r_2/r_1)+h\Big)}{\Big(hr_2 ln(r_2/r_1)+k\Big)^2}$$
$$\Big((T_1-T_\infty)2\pi L k h \Big)=\frac{\Big((T_1-T_\infty)2\pi L k h r_2\Big)\cdot \Big(hln(r_2/r_1) +h \Big)}{\Big(hr_2 ln(r_2/r_1)+k\Big)}$$
$$h \cdot r_2 \cdot ln(r_2/r_1) +k = k \cdot h \cdot ln(r_2/r_1) + kh$$
$$h \cdot r_2 \cdot ln(r_2/r_1) = k \cdot h \cdot ln(r_2/r_1) + kh-k$$
And That
s where I'm at. Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations don't look like any kind of differentiation that I'm familiar with.

The starting equation is $$\dot Q = \frac{T_1 - T_\infty}{\frac{ln(r_2/r_1)}{2\pi Lk}+\frac{1}{h(2\pi r_2L)}}=\frac{T_1 - T_\infty}{U}$$where $$U=\frac{ln(r_2/r_1)}{2\pi Lk}+\frac{1}{h(2\pi r_2L)}$$The derivative is $$\frac{d\dot{Q}}{dr_2}=-\frac{(T_1 - T_\infty)}{U^2}\frac{dU}{dr_2}$$The derivative of U with respect to $r_2$ is:  $$\frac{dU}{dr_2}=\frac{1}{2\pi Lkr_2}-\frac{1}{h(2\pi r_2^2L)}$$Now, $d\dot{Q}/dr_2$ is equal to zero if $dU/dr_2=0$.  What does that give you for $r_2$?

Comment: It will result in: $$\frac{1}{h(2\pi r_2^2 L)}=\frac{1}{2\pi Lkr_2}$$
$$\frac{r_2}{k}=\frac{1}{h}$$
$$r_2=\frac{k}{h}$$
Which is what I am looking for! =)
$$r_cr,cl = \frac{k}{h}$$
Thank you good sir!

Comment: *$r_{cr,cyl}=...$